# Plotting GLM predicted values with a categorical and a continuous predictor

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I have a generalised linear model in which one predictor is a categorical variable (binary 1/0) and one is a continuous variable.

Here's my data and my code:

```r
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)
library(datapasta)
library(ggplot2)

# my data frame: rainfall_binary is a binary vector (factor) while temp is continuous (it's temperature)

df <- data.frame(
  VH_average = c(-18.4527033816948,
                 -16.2644305598873,-16.1847107297772,-16.1971205524948,
                 -16.5239874732068,-17.2211302093816,-18.2875256347705,
                 -13.7489056675713,-14.5000673290099,-15.4042266341501,-15.1817907735829,
                 -15.6276170790517,-18.3260089724533,-15.1530169022796,
                 -16.1034334250424,-15.8582055282567,-16.2250640523659,
                 -16.9422869158206,-17.5646332225128,-15.4220277527455,
                 -15.7061506787604,-16.0053241375835,-15.6587460003135,
                 -16.848757403998,-17.9766074787419,-15.2396630934534,
                 -15.7573442344174,-15.8994493522684,-15.5906833828475,
                 -16.8160028280318),
  rainfall_binary = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                      1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  temp = c(4.05,4.05,4.05,4.05,4.05,
           4.05,7,7,7,7,7,7,4.9,4.9,4.9,4.9,4.9,4.9,5.7,
           5.7,5.7,5.7,5.7,5.7,2.25,2.25,2.25,2.25,2.25,2.25)
)


# build model

GLM.REPREX <- glm(data=df,VH_average~rainfall_binary+temp)

# create predictors


df_newtemp <- 
  data.frame(temp= seq(0,20, length=100))


df_predicts <- predict(GLM.REPREX, newdata=df_newtemp, int = 'c')
#> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): oggetto "rainfall_binary" non trovato
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It says that it doesn't find the object. I have tried in other ways, but I am new to R and I'm not even sure if what I'm doing is right. Any suggestions is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You rmodel depends on 2 variables, `temp` and `rainfall_binary`. Your `df_newtemp` has only `temp` data, but the the model needs `temp` and `rainfall_binary` to make a prediction.

Comment: Can you suggest how to add that in?

Comment: When you create your `df_newtemp`, you need to create a `rainfall_binary` variable too. You could use `df_newtemp <- 
  data.frame(temp= seq(0,20, length=100), rainfall_binary = 0)` for all 0s. Or `df_newtemp <- 
  data.frame(temp= seq(0,20, length=100), rainfall_binary = 1)` for all 1s. Or you could sample it randomly. Or you could do `df_newtemp = expand.grid(temp = seq(0, 20, length = 100), rainfall_binary = c(0, 1))` to those 100 temps at 0 and again at 1. I can't tell you what to do without knowing your goal. Why are you making these predictions and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: I want to make these predictions in order to build a plot that shows a line with the predictions based on the model over the data points.

Comment: Well, your model depends on rainfall, so the concept of a "data point" includes rainfall, and you need to think about and decide how you want rainfall to be incorporated into your plot---both in terms of data and in terms of predictions.